# insert into database with checking existence

Tags: mysql, insert

I am having two tables

> table A

```
ID | Prod_ID | Prod_Name | Price1 | Price2 |Price3
```

> table B

```
ID | Cust_ID | CUST_NAME
```

> table C

```
ID | Cust_ID | Prod_ID | Price1 | Price2 | Price3
```

the problem i am having now is that there is a method now whereas whenever there is a new insert into tableA, it will check if it already has a row in table C related to table B like the following

let says if i have the following data

```
1 | prodA | candy | 1 | 2 | 3
2 | prodB | towel | 2 | 3 | 3


1 | CustA | ccc   
2 | CustB | dddd  

1| custA | prodA | 1 | 2 | 3
2| custA | prodB | 2 | 3 | 3
3| custB | prodA | 1 | 2 | 3
4| custB | prodB | 2 | 3 | 3
```

so when i insert a new item call "cup" with price 4, 4, 4 it will first
insert into table A

```
1 | prodA | candy | 1 | 2 | 3
2 | prodB | towel | 2 | 3 | 3
3 | prodC | cup   | 4 | 4 | 4
```

and table c become

```
1| custA | prodA | 1 | 2 | 3
2| custA | prodB | 2 | 3 | 3
3| custB | prodA | 1 | 2 | 3
4| custB | prodB | 2 | 3 | 3
5| custA | prodC | 4 | 4 | 4
6| custB | prodC | 4 | 4 | 4
```

I could simply do it by deleting all elements in table C every time and create new records, however, the price of the products might change based on the customer, since the price from table B is just a reference/standard price, there will be small adjustment to every customer later on, so I wont be able to just delete the whole table and create new ones.

I am wondering if there is a easy way to do the following:
A) whenever a new product is created, check if this product is already assigned to all customers in table C, if not, insert the one that is missing

B) whenever a new customer is created, check and see what products is registered and assigned all the products to this new customer into table C

I have tried something like this

```
insert ignore into tableC (tableC.Cust, tableC.Prod) 
select tableA.custID, tableB.prodID from tableA cross join tableB 
where not exists(select tableC.Cust = tableA.custID 
and tableC.Prod = tableB.prodID)
```

i know its not correct, but that was my attempt of trying to solve this problem

Comment: Which bits did you not like/get about the answer I gave on this topic yesterday?

Comment: @P.Salmon since those keys from tableC wont be unique, therefore it might not work to check by using duplicate key? or is it possible to set both custID and prodID as keys? thank you for your reply

Comment: @P.Salmon i was able to get the problem to insert into tableC by using cross join, but I forgot about updating the price from time to time, therefore i cannot just simply delete the whole records set and insert the new one

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple columns in a unique key

Comment: @P.Salmon  but let says in TableC, if i have custA with prodA, prodB, custB with prodA, prodB, I would check in the query with "on duplicate"? that will check if there are duplicate from two columns?

Answer (score 0):

A simplified model

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(cid int, pid int, p1 int,
key tk1(cid),
unique key tu1 (cid,pid));

insert into t values
(1,1,1),(2,2,20);
```

Inserts as expected.

You would expect a second insert to fail

```
insert into t values
    (1,1,1);
```

and it does

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'tu1'
```

note that it fails on the compound unique key

if you

```
insert into t values
(1,1,30)
on duplicate key update cid = values(cid);
```

does not complain and simply updating what is already there is fine.

Comment: this should work if i have to UPDATE something, but i dun think its gonna work if i am creating new product. if i create a prodC i need to check each customer in the table (custA,custB,custC ...) and see if it has a prodC associate with it, so i have to see if custA | prodC, custB| prodC, custC|prodC are already in the table, if not insert it

Comment: Which is the point I made about adding triggers in yesterdays answer - are you familiar with triggers? If not  read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: i will take a look at the trigger first, i have never used it before, thanks for the advice